# Javascript function returns undefined, why?

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have this small piece of code that Im using to try to build a hierarchy out of a flat list (object to be precise.)

AFAIK this should work, but for some reason on the last item on the list, the findParent function is returning undefined, even though the console.log that I call right before I return does give me the right value. Any idea what could be causing this?

```
var fl = [{
    "pk": 1,
        "title": "paul",
        "parent": 3,
        "level": 2
}, {
    "pk": 2,
        "title": "ringo",
        "parent": null,
        "level": 0
}, {
    "pk": 3,
        "title": "john",
        "parent": 2,
        "level": 1
}];

var ho = {};
var looplevel = 0;
var found = 0;

function findParent (ho,id){
    for (i in ho) {
        ob = ho[i];

        if (ob.pk === id) {
            console.log(ob);
            return ob;
        }
        if (ob.children !== undefined){
            findParent(ob.children,id);
        }
    }
}

while (fl.length != found) {
    for (var i in fl) {
        var item = fl[i];
        if (item.level === looplevel) {

            item.children = {};
            if (looplevel === 0) {
                ho[item.pk] = item;
                console.log("adding " + item.title + " to hl");
                found += 1;
            } else {
                console.log("adding " + item.title + " to " + item.parent);
                ww = findParent(ho,item.parent);
                console.log(ww);
                ww.children[item.pk] = item;
                found += 1;
            }
            looplevel += 1;
        }
    }
}
console.log(ho);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function findParent (ho,id){
    for (var i in ho) {
        var ob = ho[i];

        if (ob.pk === id) {
            console.log(ob);
            return ob;
        }
        if (ob.children !== undefined){
            var parent = findParent(ob.children,id); 
            if(parent) {//if our recursion found a parent
                return parent;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Problem is you're not returning the recursive value.

**Update** have to see if parent exists so you don't leave loop early

**Update 2** just reread your code and the variable `i` and `ob` are going to be global, I corrected my answer for this variable